# Im trying to use the logic to calculate periods between dates using JavaScript and EJS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, web, ejs

Im building mini web application that on the first VIEW Im receiving "Starting Date" and "Second Date". When I click button "Rent It" to calculate the price based on the given dates. I have 4 special periods that are using different prices.

Example:
Im receiving dates between 10th and 13th of January 2020. This is 4 days of the fourthPeriod so the price should be 4*150= 600 totalPrice. If its out of these periods, there is defaultPrice which is 5. And also to display the addedDate if its between the given periods. Now im not receiving nothing, something is really wrong and Im stuck. Thanks!

This is the input

[image]

This should be the output

[image]

I made that logic (I hope its right). There are comments for understanding.

```
//TODO: Fire function on load and  get the start date, the end date and make the array
function getTotalPrice(arrPeriods, rentDateStart, rentDateEnd, defaultPriceOfDay) {

let totalPrice = 0;

let defaultPrice = 5;

let startOfPeriod = new Date();
let endOfPeriod = new Date(startOfPeriod.getTime() + (48 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
let month = startOfPeriod.getMonth();
let daysCountOfPeriod = [];
let day = 1000*60*60*24;
let diff = (endOfPeriod.getTime() - startOfPeriod.getTime()) / day;

//TODO: Calculate all separate days from start date to end date and put them in an array
for ( let i = 0 ; i <= diff; i++)
{
    let a = startOfPeriod.getTime() + day * i;
    let b = new Date(a);
    let c = (b.getDate() + "-" + (b.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + b.getFullYear());
    let separator = c.split('-');
    let cDate = new Date(separator[2], separator[1] - 1, separator[0]);

    daysCountOfPeriod.push(cDate)
}

//TODO: Declare the period of the different periods and the daily cost rate during this period
let firstPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,1), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,4), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 1), pricePerDay: 2};
let secondPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,3), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,8), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 2), pricePerDay: 60};
let thirdPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,5), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,6), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 1), pricePerDay: 15};
let fourthPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,8), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,15), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 15), pricePerDay: 150};

//TODO: Making an array with all the given periods
let allPeriods = [firstPeriod, secondPeriod, thirdPeriod, fourthPeriod]


//TODO: Checks how many dates there are in the array and start the loop
for (let u = 0; u < daysCountOfPeriod.length; u++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < allPeriods.length; j++) {
        if (daysCountOfPeriod[u] >= allPeriods[j].startDate && daysCountOfPeriod[u] <= allPeriods[j].endDate) {
            //TODO: Add costRate of this date to totalPrice
            totalPrice = totalPrice + allPeriods[j].pricePerDay;
        }
        else {
            totalPrice = totalPrice + defaultPrice;
        }
    }
}
//TODO: Return the total price
return totalPrice;
}
```

Now I want to implement this to the project using EJS. Thats is what have I done.

SERVER.JS - Here is the server logic

```
    const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"))

let daysCountOfPeriod = [];

//TODO: Get methods
app.get("/result", function (req, res){
    res.render("result", {
        daysCountOfPeriod: daysCountOfPeriod
    });
});

app.get("/", function (req, res){
    res.render("dates")
})

//TODO: Post methods
app.post("/", function (req, res){

    const gettingDates = {
        startingDate: req.body.start,
        endingDate: req.body.end
    };

    daysCountOfPeriod.push(gettingDates);
    res.redirect("/result")
});

//TODO: Shows that our server is running at localhost:3000
app.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log("Server is running!")
});
```

This is dates.ejs basic html:

```
<main class="form-signin">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <img class="mb-4" src="images/logo.png" alt="" width=150 height="150">

        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="date" class="form-control top" name="start" placeholder="Starting Date">
            <label for="floatingInput">Starting Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="date" class="form-control bottom" name="end" placeholder="Ending Date">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Ending Date</label>
        </div>

        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="submit" name="button">Rent It!</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Bike rental company</p>
    </form>
</main>

</body>
```

And lastly the result.ejs

```
<body class="text-center">

<main class="form-signin">
    <section>
        <img class="mb-4" src="images/logo.png" alt="" width=150 height="150">

        <% let totalPrice = 0; %>
        <% let added = ""; %>

        <% let firstPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,1), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,4), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 1), pricePerDay: 2}; %>
        <% let secondPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,3), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,8), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 2), pricePerDay: 60}; %>
        <% let thirdPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,5), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,6), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 1), pricePerDay: 15}; %>
        <% let fourthPeriod = {startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,8), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,15), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 15), pricePerDay: 150}; %>

        <% let allPeriods = [firstPeriod, secondPeriod, thirdPeriod, fourthPeriod] %>

        <% for (let u = 0; u < daysCountOfPeriod.length; u++) { %>
            <% for(let j = 0; j < allPeriods.length; j++) { %>
                <%  if (daysCountOfPeriod[u] >= allPeriods[j].startDate && daysCountOfPeriod[u] <= allPeriods[j].endDate) { %>
                    //Add price of this date to totalPrice %>
                    <% totalPrice = totalPrice + allPeriods[j].pricePerDay; %>
                    <% added = allPeriods[j].addingDate; %>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
        <h1>Total Price</h1>
        <h3><%= totalPrice %>$</h3>
        <h3>Added on: <%= added %></h3>
    </section>
</main>

</body>
```

I want to take the date "daysCountOfPeriod" into the inputs, make it to the array and then loop it and check it for the given period and to get a proper result, now im not getting nothing. Im a beginner , so I will need some help.

Example: Im receiving dates between 10th and 13th of January 2020. This is 4 days of the fourthPeriod so the price should be 4*150= 600 totalPrice. If its out of these periods, there is defaultPrice which is 5. And also to display the addedDate if its between the given periods. Now im not receiving nothing, something is really wrong and Im stuck. Thanks!

Comment: "I will need some help" is not a good question for Stack Overflow. The question should be specific about a specific problem you bumped into: with an example of input, expected output, and the output you get instead.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit it now.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]. If the EJS all work as expected, and this is a clientside JavaScript problem, then PLEASE post RENDERED HTML and JavaScript ONLY

Comment: If you have issues with BOTH the EJS AND the JavaScript, then please ask TWO questions. One thing at a time

Comment: @mplungjan Its about EJS and implementing the logic. The other codes are for understanding the problem

Comment: Too much code. Break it down in small problems ans ask one at a time. Your description is very personal, make it technical: I have 4 periods called `firstPeriod, secondPeriod...` Their values come from the server as `{startDate: new Date(2020,1-1,1), endDate: new Date(2020,1-1,4), addingDate: new Date(2019, 6, 1), pricePerDay: 2}` -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to:

- Use a user-defined start and end date to get the "Price per day" and "Added Date" from a list of pre-defined periods.
- If no matching period found, use "5" for the "Price per day" instead.
- Get the number of days between the start and end date.
- Multiply the price per day by the numbers days between the start and end date, to get the total price.

In order to make the answer as minimal as possible, I reduced your example a bit and made it work for client-side JavaScript, but you can easily put this into your EJS instead.

JsFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/pnjc7fsq/

```js
// appends 00:00:00 time
var start_date = new Date((document.querySelector('#start_date').value || '') + ' 00:00:00').getTime();
// appends 24:00:00 time to target the start of the next day;
var end_date = new Date((document.querySelector('#end_date').value || '') + ' 24:00:00').getTime();
var period = periods.find(function(period) {
  return start_date >= period.startDate && end_date <= period.endDate;
});
var days = (end_date - start_date) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
var price = period ? period.pricePerDay * days : 5 * days;
var output = 'Total Price: ' + price + ' (Price per day:' + (period && period.pricePerDay || 5) + ', Days: ' + days + ')<br>' +
              'Adding Date: ' + (period ? period.addingDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10) : '');
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = output;
```